# clang++ warning: "warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, warnings, llvm

Having installed LLVM on Ubuntu 16.04 using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install clang llvm
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
nlykkei@nlykkei-VirtualBox:~$ clang++ -g toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs` -o toy
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'; did you mean
      '-Wno-uninitialized'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
1 warning generated.
```

To be specific, I follow the tutorial: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html on the LLVM website.

The version of LLVM is 3.8.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of clang / llvm do you have?

Comment: the maybe_uninitialized attribute is c++17 isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

This is [a bug in `llvm-config`](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24979).  Long story short, `llvm-config` outputs `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized` which is not a warning implemented by clang.

One possible workaround is to add an extra flag squelching warnings about unknown warnings.

```
clang++ <your flags> -Wno-unknown-warning-option `llvm-config ...`
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning comes when you recently upgraded your sdk-build-tools with 30.x

I resolved the issue by downgrading sdk-build-tools by 29.x.

Delete all the intermediate files , they will be auto generate again.

Clean Project .

Invalidate Cashes and Restart the Project.

Woow, warning has been removed now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer mentioned here https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/18986 might help. Mostly changing `Wno-maybe-uninitialized` with `-Wno-uninitialized` in / bazel/envoy_internal.bzl