# clang-tidy reporting unknown warnings

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

I have a CMake build using GCC. I generated compile_commands.json then ran clang-tidy but I'm getting hundreds of:

```
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'; did you mean '-Wno-uninitialized'? [clang-diagnostic-unknown-warning-option]
error: unknown warning option '-Wno-psabi' [clang-diagnostic-unknown-warning-option]
```

How can I disable or remove these warnings? I saw [clang++ warning: “warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673546/clang-warning-warning-unknown-warning-option-wno-maybe-uninitialized) but adding "-Wno-unknown-warning-option" gives me an error:

```
run-clang-tidy-3.8.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -Wno-unknown-warning-option
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clang++ warning: "warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673546/clang-warning-warning-unknown-warning-option-wno-maybe-uninitialized)

Comment: But the answer given there doesn't work for clang-tidy.

Comment: If your CMake project adds given compiler options unconditionally, the only thing you can do is probably to fix the CMake project itself.

Comment: It's not unconditional - those options are valid with GCC.

Comment: But they are not valid for clang. By "unconditionally" I meant that the project doesn't check compiler before adding the option. Or did you configure the project for gcc, but built it with clang? If so, what else do you want?

Comment: I built it with GCC then used the compile_commands.json to run clang-tidy, as I said above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try appending `-extra-arg=-Wno-unknown-warning-option` to clang-tidy command line.

Using `-extra-arg=` asks clang-tidy to pass `-Wno-unknown-warning-option` to the underlying clang. Otherwise, it tries to interpret it as a clang-tidy flag.

**Edit:**

The `run-clang-tidy.py` script supports `-extra-arg` starting version 5.0. In prior versions, you'd need to edit the script and add that `-extra-arg` manually.

If you're on Ubuntu 16.04, you can get `clang-tidy-5.0` from:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/xenial/main/base/clang-tidy-5.0

Comment: "run-clang-tidy-3.8.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -extra-arg=-Wno-unknown-warning-option". Do I need a newer version of clang-tidy?

Comment: Right, you would need `run-clang-tidy-5.0.py` for that, if you're running the script (`-extra-arg` is recognized also by `clang-tidy-3.8`, but only in the 5.0 script the argument is recognized by the script and passed on to clang-tidy).

Comment: Better use `--extra-arg=-Wno-error=unknown-warning-option`

Answer (score 3):

For me,

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy-8;--extra-arg=-Wno-error=unknown-warning-option")
```

solved the issue when running clang-tidy from within CMake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I generated compile_commands.json using GCC. When I used Clang, everything is fine. It seems that clang-tidy/run_clang_tidy.py has a problem with processing compile_commands.json generated by a different compiler than Clang.