# clang-tidy reporting many error: unknown argument

Tags: c, clang-tidy

I am running an embedded `C` project based on a `tricore-gcc` compiler.
I made a `compile_commands.json` file that works well.
However,  there are some arguments that `clang-tidy` cannot recognize.
For example I get the following

```
error: unknown argument: '-fstrict-volatile-bitfields' [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

when I run `clang-tidy`.
This is not a surprise of course, since `-fstrict-volatile-bitfields` is an option for `gcc` but not for `clang-tidy`.
However, I would like to suppress output messages due to unknown compiler options.
I tried to append `--extra-arg=-Wno-unknown-warning-option` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006405/clang-tidy-reporting-unknown-warnings) but the problem persists.

Comment: Just remove the `-fstrict-volatile-bitfields` argument from your `.clang-tidy` file or if you give it as a command line argument to `clang-tidy`. It should be an argument to the compiler, not to `clang-tidy`.

Comment: You mean `.json` file? I could do that but I have too many arguments and too many files. If there is an option to ignore the compiler arguments not recognized by clang-tidy but that appear in the `.json` file it would be way better.

Comment: Yeah, if it's in your `json` file and passed as an argument to `clang-tidy`, remove it. It should be passed to the compiler only. You need to have (at least) one set of options for the compiler and another for `clang-tidy` but `clang-tidy` usually runs without options and reads the nearest `.clang-tidy` config file, so, invoke `clang-tidy` without arguments (except the file to check) to start with.

Comment: Yes, that would be the best, but the problem relies if there is some file with some specific flag that is recognized by both `clang-tidy` and `gcc`. In that case shall I add it or not to the argument list for `clang-tidy`? And I should I make this check for each single file in the `json`? We are talking of hundreds of `.c` files.

Comment: `clang-tidy` usually don't require any flags/options and the flags/options it does recognize are not recognized by `gcc`. I haven't worked with `compile_commands.json` so I don't know to make general rules as in plain old `Makefile`s I'm afraid.

Comment: It's OK! :) I need `clang-tidy` to parse some flags from the `.json?` file though (for example to specify where some header file is located) :) Let's see if I get some answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using `clang-tidy` for a project compiled with GCC. The two compilers have different set of recognized flags. My `compile_commands.json`, which was generated by [intercept-build](https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build), contained a number of options used by GCC that clang-tidy did not understand.

I solved this by a somewhat hackish solution of redacting the compile database before initiating the static analysis pass.

My script contains a number of Sed lines similar to this:

```
sed -i -E 's#-fconserve-stack##g' compile_commands.json
sed -i -E 's#-maccumulate-outgoing-args##g' compile_commands.json
sed -i -E 's#-mindirect-branch-register##g' compile_commands.json
sed -i -E 's#-mindirect-branch=thunk-extern##g' compile_commands.json
sed -i -E 's#-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3##g' compile_commands.json
sed -i -E 's#-mfunction-return=thunk-extern##g' compile_commands.json
```

This way, the unsupported flags are made invisible to clang-tidy, which allows to work without errors.